# Firebase onComplete firing to soon

Tags: android, firebase

I'm trying out Firebase on android and using tests to do so. Now since tests are supposed to be isolated I have

```
@Override
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    super.tearDown();
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    new Firebase(URL).setValue(null, new Firebase.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) {
            latch.countDown();
        }
    });
    latch.await();
}
```

Where `URL` points to my Firebase app. I've noticed that some of my tests read data inserted from others. I made 2 assumptions: `setValue(null)` on my app url will clear my entire app and `onComplete` will be fired after all data is gone from the server. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the issue wasn't deletion, I didn't remove my listeners from Firebase and they are not bound to a single Firebase instance. This test illustrates the issue.

```
public void testListenerMagic() throws Exception {
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    new Firebase(URL).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            assertEquals("asdf", dataSnapshot.getValue());
            latch.countDown();
        }
    });
    new Firebase(URL).child("foo").setValue("asdf");
    await(latch);
}
```

Since Firebase does not yet allow you to remove all listeners, I'll have to remember to remove them or workaround for testing.